# microsoft cognitive face find similar return empty list

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face

Now I want to use the api Face to extract facial appearance with 'find similar'.Therefore, we are testing the ' open api testing ' on their homepage, but the result is an empty list against description which in their official document.Do you know how to solve this?

In their document the result like this:

```
    [
        {
            "persistedFaceId" : "015839fb-fbd9-4f79-ace9-7675fc2f1dd9",    
            "confidence" : 0.82
        },
    ...
    ]
```

but in testing console:

```
[]
```

I created face_list which named `test` and add two face in the face_list.
And in `Detect`, I extracted `persistedFaceId`. I put the `persistedFaceId` in `request body` like this:

```
{    
    "faceId":persistedFaceId,
    "faceListId":test,  
}
```

Comment: `detect` should return a `faceId`, not a `persistedFaceId`.  Also note that the faceId is only valid for 24-hours.

Answer (score 0):

In findsimilar utility one of the important parameter is **mode**.

i.e.

> "faceId":"Your Detected face id",
>
> "faceListId":"test"
>
> "mode": "matchPerson"

mode defines which type of output you want.
If mode is **matchPerson** then Find similar works to find perosn similarity.

If mode is **matchFace** then Find similar works to find faces similarity.

Hope you can understand that person similarity have more filters then faces similarity. And some times if not found similarity then it returns null.